# Send unanswered questions to email in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to configure dialogflow to handle unanswered question. What I'd like is...

- User asks a question
- Intent not found
- Default Fallback says 'sorry, can I get your email'
- User provides email
- Webhook sends an email to an admin inbox with the original question in it so somebody can pick it up and reply when they can.

So I can get most of this working except making sure the NodeJS webhook has the original question, as the actual intent that's triggering it is 'provide an email', not the original failed question.

Any advice very welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be to take advantage of [Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview). This saves a database operation until you have all the information you need from the user, and helps make sure you are collecting the email address at an appropriate time.

Under this scheme:

- A Fallback Intent triggers the webhook, which

  - Responds asking for the email address
  - Includes a Context as part of the response with the question in a parameter
- You would then have another Intent which has this Context set as the Input Context. When this Intent is triggered

  - Send the request to the inbox, save the info in a database, whatever.
  - Reply to the user and clear the Context.
- You may have other Intents, or a Fallback Intent, which has this Context as the Input Context as well. These may provide replies saying you need an email address to forward the question, or cautioning them that if they don't provide it, you won't be able to get them an answer. This handles the case if they don't wish to provide an address, have changed their mind, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer...

- Default fallback triggers the webhook, providing question and sessionID which is then stored in a database
- Fallback asks for email address
- Provides_email intent triggers webhook again, which then updates the original record to include the email address, and sends the request to the inbox.

Comment: This isn't bad, but does have the issue about leaving the database with garbage accumulating if the user chooses not to provide their email address.